# Updating datagridview row background color with datatriggers and IValueConverter

Tags: wpf, datagridview, datatrigger, ivalueconverter

I have a datagridview and am trying to dynamically update the background color of a row depending on the result of a comparison between one column and two others. My datagridview is bound to a datatable. The three different columns in the datagridview are min, max, and present. The values in the min and max columns are static and do not change. The values in the present column for each row update dynamically.

I use a class called MinMaxTester that implements the IValueConverter interface to compare contents of cells to return a brush color.

With the solution I have implemented, I note that the background color sometimes updates. The datagridview is part of a tab item within a tab control. When the datagridview is not visible to the user, the background color will usually update. When the datagridview is visible to the user (IE the tab item within the tab control has been selected), the background color will not update.

I am wondering what I need to change in my solution so that the row background color will always update?

XAML file Code

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MinMaxTester x:Key="MinMaxTester"/>
</Window.Resources>

<DataGrid.Columns>
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Present" Binding="{Binding Present}"/>
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Min" Binding="{Binding Min}"/>
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Max" Binding="{Binding Max}"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>

<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
         <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MinMaxTester}}"/>
    </Style>
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Implementation Code

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(DataRowView),typeof(Brush))]
public class MinMaxTester: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object datagridrow, Type target, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int min, max, present;
        DataRowView r = datagridrow as DataRowView;
        min = int.Parse(r["Min"].ToString());
        max = int.Parse(r["Max"].ToString());
        present = int.Parse(r["Present"].ToString());
        if (present >= min && present <= max) 
            return Brushes.Green;
        else
            return Brushes.Red;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object datagridrow, Type target, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Not using the ConvertBack function in  MinMaxTester");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

have you tried this ?

```
<Window.Resources>
        <my:RowBackgroundColorConverter x:Key="rowBackgroundColorConverterResource"></my:RowBackgroundColorConverter>
    </Window.Resources>
```

---

```
   <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding fieldXXX, Converter={StaticResource converterXXX}}"></Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

**And the converter code:**

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace XXX.Converters
{
    public class RowBackgroundColorConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        private readonly Color expiredColor = Colors.Red;

        private readonly Color normalColor = Colors.Gray;

        public object Convert(
            object value,
            Type targetType,
            object parameter,
            CultureInfo culture)
        {

            if (XXXXX)
                return new SolidColorBrush(expiredColor);

                return new SolidColorBrush(normalColor);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(
            object value, 
            Type targetType, 
            object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your `Present` is doing and where, but this might work what you need (w/o changing your code too much)

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource converter}" Mode="OneWay">
    <MultiBinding.Bindings>
        <Binding Path="Present" />
        <Binding Path="" />
    </MultiBinding.Bindings>
</MultiBinding>
```

...and then in your converter (which is now `IMultiValueConverter` - all similar just one more field) you have both values. You use 'row' to calculate.
...and you use direct binding to `Present` to trigger the change.

You also need to make sure that whatever 'holds' the Present - have INotifyPropertyChanged as mentioned already.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you, you just answered a very similar question I had as well with this answer. TIL about multivalueconverter

Answer (score 0):

You said you are binding to a `DataTable`, however data in a `DataTable` do not implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx), so will not raise a `PropertyChange` notification to tell the UI that it needs to update.

I would suggest switching to binding your `DataGrid` from a `DataTable` to an `ObservableCollection<MyDataObject>`, and make sure `MyDataObject` implements [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx)